# How to draw normal map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, normals, texture-painting, normal-map

How can I draw (not bake) normal map over my model, like a texture in texture paint mode? Render cycles.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can draw a normal map directly like that, at least not easily. You could however pain a bump map

Comment: Check this, it's possible: https://youtu.be/TMbx5UVjz7Q

Comment: @LukeD Thank you! I downloaded the blend file from the creator of this video, but i can't understand how to use it yet...

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yes, but I need to have a normal map at the end. However, I think I will try to turn bump texture into a normal map.

Comment: @Rumata Check my answer, I think you'll manage to get this working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easier and more intuitive to paint a height-map, then convert it into a normal map:

[image]

There is GIMP normalmap plugin, Photoshop plugins like xNormal, apps like CrazyBump and a lot of others. These all can do the conversion. Also, it can be done through Blender Baking.

If you already have a normal map, and you need to add to it, you can combine normal maps with *overlay blending* operation - generally it is ok enough but note that it is not the correct operation - more on combining normal maps is here: [Blending in detail](http://blog.selfshadow.com/publications/blending-in-detail/).

You can also paint directly into normal maps:

- you can **erase** with RGB[128,128,255] brush
- you can **average** with ordinary *Soften* (smooth) brush
- you can **smudge** with *Smear* brush
- you can **paint** with a special texture brush:

  1. create a brush height texture that you want to paint with
  2. convert to normal map texture

     [image]
  3. paint with this texture in overlay mode. It will be like sculpting, but on a texture. The brush color must be white, spacing of strokes very low and strength of brush also low

Comment: Worth noting that the conversion can be done with baking within blender. You can set the height map as bump map in BI and then bake it to a tangent space normal map, no need for external software.

Comment: @Sazerac Yep, very true. Thanks for adding this. I don't paint textures in Blender so that makes Blender baking external software for me and those plugins actually internal, that's why it didn't hit me as solution right away.

Answer (score 3):

### Result:

[image: Final]

### Credits:

First of all this is not my work, it's from [riceart41](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/83680) on BlendSwap (download this file to make all of this to work). You can find more information on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/TMbx5UVjz7Q) and on [BlenderArtists](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?393277-PBR-Specular-shader-in-blenders-viewport).

### Overview:

There is no accurate tutorial from the creator of this method but I've managed to get it to work in a way presented below:

[image: overview]

You'll need to create **Paint Slot**, assign it to **Height Map Image** in **Texture Group** and connect **Normals** to shaders.

Don't forget to set **Texture X** and **Texture Y size** in **Bump_to_normal** group accordingly to created **Paint Slot**.

That's really all you'll need to do.

I don't know what sorcery is behind this but it is converting **Height Map** to **Normal Map** pretty good.

Comment: Invaluable information. Thank you very much.