# Non Color Data Procedural Normals

Tags: normals, normal-map, procedural

So I was trying to reproduce this tutorial for Lightwave on Blender:
http://iaian7.com/lightwave/SoapFoamSurfacing

Basically the guy uses a node setup to get procedural Black&White bubbles which he then uses to generate Normal Maps using a custom setup. 
You can get the same B&W bubbles using a Voronoi texture on Blender then using a Minimum(Math) node to isolate the shapes (or use a Color Ramp instead).

The problem is, if you feed the result of the B&W bubbles directly into a normal map node you get pure black, which is wrong.

When you input it firstly into a Bump node to convert B&W to normal values, then into a Normal Map node, the result is too dark, is as if you were using a normal image without selecting Non-Color-Data.

For comparison, this is the result using the following normal map image:
[image]
Here is the same, but with Non-Color-Data selected, and Color selected on the right:
[image]
As you can see, left is correct, right is wrong.

Then here is the node setup for procedural bubbles:
[image]
The result is not exactly the same pallette as a normal map image would be, but I tried keep going anyway.
This is the result of that bump node going into a glass shader:
[image]
As you can see, no "bubbliness" is present, they are kind of flat.
If you feed the Bump node into a Normal Map node, this is the result:
[image]

So I'm not being capable to reach a result similar to what I'd get with a regular normal map image. I wanted it to be procedural so that I could put it in any object instantly, without repetition no matter the size and shape.

At first I thought that the output of a Bump node was being interpreted as being Color Data, instead of Non-Color Data, so these are the things that I tried:

1) follow this node setup to convert from sRGB to Linear (and the inverse as well):https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?251208-sRGB-lt-gt-Linear-Nodegroup

These are the terrible results:
[image]
[image]

2)Then I tried using this node setup which is apparently for Procedural baking of normal maps on cycles: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?348799-Baking-Cycles-Procedural-Normals-to-Texture

This was the result:
[image]
Still too dark... apparently the node setup did nothing to "fix" the output of the bump map.

Anyone have any ideas?
This is the blend file:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=46983

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Overview:

I think that everything should be ok with just Bump node. There is a method to convert Height Map (B&W) to the same Normal Map as in your first image, but this produce the same results.

### Comparison:

**First my node setup:**

[image: node]

> **Bump_to_normal** group is not mine, see **Credits** at the bottom.

In **Texture Group Node** there is **Height Map** created from **Voronoi Texture**.

**Bump node:**

[image: bump]

**Bump_to_normal node:**

[image: b2m]

As you can see there is no difference at all, no matter from what map you feed **Normal** input in **Glass** node.

### Solution:

I think your problem lays just in **Distance** value in **Bump** node. It's to high.

### About Bump to Normal:

I can't tell you how this node setup is working, there is little to none info from the author (check Credits). But I'll show you how to set it up:

[image: bump to norm]

1. In **Texture Node Group** > **Height Map Image** set your **Height map**. It could be any B&W input. **Image Texture, Texture Paint, Procedural,** you name it.
2. Connect **Bump_to_normal Node Group** to **Normal Map** and then just to any **Normal** input you want.

### Blend file:

[image]

### Credits:

First of all this is not my work, it's from [riceart41](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/83680) on BlendSwap (download this file to make all of this to work). You can find more information on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/TMbx5UVjz7Q) and on [BlenderArtists](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?393277-PBR-Specular-shader-in-blenders-viewport).

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was not making proper use of the Bump node... anyway that node setup bump_to_normal can be really useful in other situations, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Arkhangels Check my answer here for other use option: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77088/how-to-draw-normal-map It wasn't accepted though...