# Draw Normal, Bump and Specular Map manually in Blender

Tags: texturing, normal-map, height-map

I am going to make a rusty nut. Some portion of it is still glossy, but most of them are covered with rust.

Now for rust I have an image. I want to paint normal map, bump map and specular map manually in Blender.

Previously I used insane bump plugins in Gimp to make those maps. But I noticed that using those maps in Blender nodes doesn't look that great. No matter how much I try. So I am planning to draw everything manually in Blender. And it is justified because I might need custom adjustment.

How to draw Normal map, Specular map and bump map manually in Blender?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77088/how-to-draw-normal-map?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa You may find your answer here on the 2nd post.

Comment: @hawkenfox but that question doesn't address othe two maps I want to draw manually :(

Comment: This question is too vague. Generating different maps has never been the proper approach to get good results. How to achieve/paint a good texture depends totally on what kind of material you're making. Rust you could generate with Musgrave noise and color ramp that affects color, specularity, roughness and displacement for example.

Comment: @Man_From_India I can understand painting normals, as for specular and bump, I always find that it's too much effort with free and paid packages that could generate them very well. Saves time too ... I might just paint them in blender by the fraction, touching up.